# SQL Server Triggers on Specific Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

Afternoon all!

I'm working on a large database at work, and they've specifically asked me to implement triggers into the database.

Basically, we have a set of tables all containing different information, but if, in one particular table, a certain range of values are entered into the 'fieldID' column, I need it to *trigger*.

In this case, if a user INSERT data, with the fieldID >= 4 AND fieldID <=9, I need the SQL Server to trigger, with a command of inserting the data to a different table.

For example,

```
 INSERT INTO myTestTable(state, process, fieldID) VALUES ('ACTIVE', 13,9);
 (and the database actually performing)
 INSERT INTO myFieldTable(state, process, fieldID) VALUES ('ACTIVE', 13,9);

 INSERT INTO myTestTable(state, process, fieldID) VALUES ('ACTIVE', 13,42);
 (and the database actually performing)
 INSERT INTO myTestTable(state, process, fieldID) VALUES ('ACTIVE', 13,42);
```

I've found loads of stuff online about triggers and how they work in when a new record is entered in general, but nothing for specific data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the simplest form, you can write a `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger to achieve what you are trying. something like below

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_testoninsert on myTestTable
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
IF inserted.fieldID >= 4 AND inserted.fieldID <=9

INSERT INTO myFieldTable(state, process, fieldID) 
select state, process, fieldID
from inserted;
END;
GO
```

Comment: Thanks! but how is it referencing the "inserted"?

Comment: @WillWhitehead, Good question; why not read and understand the same using MSDN document. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179288%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: @WillWhitehead, `inserted` is a intermediator table and so the data will get inserted to that table first before it make it's way to actual table. You can reference the data directly from this table and perform some validation/manipulation on it.

Comment: I just read all the techNet stuff - I fully understand it now, your example really helped

Cheers

Comment: Your trigger doesn't work. You are checking the first row values and sending the entire contents of `inserted` to the secondary table. And you don't insert into the main table at all. You don't need an `if` statement. Just two `insert` statements, one to the primary and the other to the secondary. `insert into myFieldTable(state, process, fieldID) select state, process, fieldID from inserted where fieldID between 4 and 9;` and `insert into myTestTable(state, process, fieldID) select state, process, fieldID from inserted where fieldID < 4 or field ID > 9;` That's it. Nothing fancy.